# 500: Internal Server Error on creating first Web API Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just created a MVC 4 Application and chose Empty Web APi template. Visual Studio 2012 created the project successfully. However when I run the application using Visual Studio with url `http://localhost:48687/`, I am getting `500: Internal Server Error` (using Chrome Inspect Element). And the browser says, `This Page Cannot Be Displayed`.

How can we rectify it?

**REFERENCES**

1. [ASP.NET Web API in MVC tutorial](http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/web-api-in-mvc-tutorial.aspx)
2. [ASP.NET Web API vs. ASP.NET MVC “APIs”](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-api-vs-asp-net-mvc-apis/)
3. [REST based CRUD operations with ASP.NET Web API](http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/rest-based-crud-operations-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx)
4. [channel9 - Building a Service Layer with ASP.NET Web API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASP-NET-Jump-Start/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASPNET-Jump-Start-04-Building-a-Service-Layer-with-ASPNET-Web-API)
5. [channel9 - Building Services for Any Client with ASP.NET Web API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-036)
6. [channel9 - Build RESTful APIs with ASP.NET Web API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2013/DEV-H303#fbid=)
7. [channel9 - Securing ASP.NET Web APIs](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Securing-ASPNET-Web-APIs)
8. [channel9 - Dan Roth Takes Us on a Deep Dive into Web API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Dan-Roth-Takes-Us-on-a-Deep-Dive-into-Web-API)
9. [channel9 - ASP.NET Web API: Web Services for Websites, Modern Apps, and Mobile Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B360#fbid=)
10. [channel9 - Building HTTP Services with ASP.NET Web API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DEV309)
11. [channel9 - Wrapping Up the Web API Tour with Yao Huang Lin](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Wrapping-Up-the-Web-API-Tour-with-Yao-Huang-Lin)
12. [msdn - Enabling and Customizing ASP.NET Web API Services Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201748.aspx)

Comment: Run from server or set "customErrors" to "Off" to see the actual error.

Comment: @UweKeim No information obtained after adding `customErrors mode="Off"`. And this is a white error screen; not the yellow error screen.

Comment: I haven't used Web API since it was just released, but Empty Web API sounds like a project which contains only Web Api controller. This would mean that there is no website to show when you browse to http://localhost:48687/. If you try a request to your service (using fiddler or whatever), does that work?

Comment: Can you debug the service and change your settings so that you are notified about each exception when it is thrown (menu: Debug->Exceptions)? This might help you in finding the cause.

Comment: Reference: [The ASP.NET MVC & Web API Magazine](https://flipboard.com/section/the-asp.net-mvc-%26-web-api-magazine-b2XTBi)

Comment: and [SPA Primer with Durandal, Knockout, and Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/blog/spa-primer-durandal-knockout-and-breeze)